# What is the code in HTML for making an image, or a gif animation- to appear in FRONT of an embeded movie clip (lets say from you tube)?

Tags: html

What is the code in HTML for making an image, or a gif animation- to appear in FRONT of an embeded movie clip (lets say from you tube)?

Answer (score 1):

The [CSS z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_z-index.asp) property may be what you're looking for, it determines the drawing ordering of items that overlap each other.

Comment: But since it's a flash movie in question, wmode="transparent" must be added to the swf in order for it to work as desired.